# Как в приложении JavaFX добавить функцию часов?

Tags: javafx

Пишу на JavaFx программку "Информационное ж/д табло". Возникла проблема: не могу найти класс, отвечающий за поле, в котором идет, заранее пользователем установленное, время.
Есть вариант: найти посторонний класс, который работает с временем. После, добавляя значение времени в Label, через отдельный поток заставить время идти.
Возможно, это не самая лучшая идея, но все же, был бы рад помощи в реализации.

P.S Если есть другие идеи - буду рад выслушать.

Answer (score 1):

Один из наиболее простых вариантов:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


public class App extends Application {

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Label uiTimer = new Label();
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> uiTimer.setText(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter)))
        );
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(uiTimer, 100, 50));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```